# PROC Means for dummy variables in SAS

Tags: variables, sas, mean, proc

I have created a dummy variable in SAS, that in any given year takes the value 1 if both countries are members of the EMU and 0 otherwise in that year.

```
emu1=0;
if country1 in ("AUT","BEL","FIN","FRA","DEU","IRL","ITA","NLD","PRT","ESP") and year>1998 then emu1=1;
if country1 in ("GRC") and year>2000 then emu1=1;
emu2=0;
if country2 in ("AUT","BEL","FIN","FRA","DEU","IRL","ITA","NLD","PRT","ESP") and year>1998 then emu2=1;
if country2 in ("GRC") and year>2000 then emu2=1;
emu=0;
if emu1=1 and emu2=1 then emu=1;
```

Now I want to see the mean for the variable `gdp1` for countries which takes the value `emu=0` and for countries which takes the value `emu=1`, respectively. How do I do that?

I know that I can use the PROC MEANS:

```
PROC MEANS DATA=gravitydata mean MAXDEC=2;
VAR gdp1;
run;
```

But this shows the mean for all the observation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a `class` statement, this groups by the specified variable.

```
PROC MEANS DATA=gravitydata mean MAXDEC=2;
CLASS emu;
VAR gdp1;
run;
```

Comment: I have tried that, but I geet the following error:

`507  PROC MEANS DATA=gravitydata mean MAXDEC=2;
508  CLASS emu;
ERROR: Variable EMU not found.
509  VAR gdp1;
510  run;`

Comment: When you created the EMU variable, what did you call the dataset?

Comment: Ahh, thanks. Me who have forgot to change the data. It works fine now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Amazing debugging without even seeing the code by Keith :)